# How does one tell CXF wsdl2Java to generate java code for specific version of XMLBeans

Tags: cxf, wsdl2java

I am facing any issue with CXF wsdl2java. I need to generate Java code using CXF wsdl2java with xmlbeans databinding for specific version of xmlbeans.

It looks like by default its generating for 2.5.0. In my case, I would like to generate code for xmlbeans 2.4.0

CXF wsdl2Java command specifies the databinding with -db option but looking for how to give the version of databinding.  Can't find how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Sometimes it is possible to replace JAX-WS tooling runtime for utility like `wsdl2java`: look for it classpath and you will discover yourself. If that is not possible, take `wsdl2java` from earlier CXF package.

Answer (score 0):

CXF will just use the version of XMLBeans that it finds on the classpath.   Thus, if you need 2.4.0, just remove the 2.5.0 jars that CXF provides and make sure the 2.4.0 versions are available on the classpath.   That said, I'm not sure if CXF has tested with 2.4.0 for a while.